# Did Allah speak to any other Messengers other than Moses Directly?

Tags: allah, prophets, revelation

Did Allah speak to any other Messengers other than Moses Directly ?
any proof for this in Quran or Sunnah.

Comment: Prophet Adam(**I guess**).... because he was so close to Allah after being created...

Comment: And of course Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) but only behind a veil.

Answer (score 1):

Allah spoke to Adam(A.S), Moses(A.S) and Mohamed (S.A.W), (Mohammed S.A.W in the Isra and Mi'raj exactly in the Mi'raj) .

Sources are in arabic:

1. Adam:

عن أبي أمامة أن رجلا قال : يا رسول الله أنبيٌّ كان آدم ؟ قال : ( نَعَمْ مُكَلَّمٌ ) قال : فكم كان بينه وبين نوح ؟ قال : ( عَشْرَةُ قُرُون )

رواه ابن حبان في " صحيحه " ( 14 / 69 ) وصححه شعيب الأرناؤط محقق الكتاب .

2. Moise : in the quran.
3. Mohammed:

وهو ثابت في رحلة المعراج إلى السماء ، وفيها قوله صلى الله عليه وسلم :
( فَرَجَعْتُ فَمَرَرْتُ عَلَى مُوسَى فَقَالَ : بِمَا أُمِرْتَ ؟ قَالَ : أُمِرْتُ بِخَمْسِينَ صَلَاةً كُلَّ يَوْمٍ ، قَالَ : إِنَّ أُمَّتَكَ لَا تَسْتَطِيعُ خَمْسِينَ صَلَاةً كُلَّ يَوْمٍ وَإِنِّي وَاللَّهِ قَدْ جَرَّبْتُ النَّاسَ قَبْلَكَ وَعَالَجْتُ بَنِي إِسْرَائِيلَ أَشَدَّ الْمُعَالَجَةِ فَارْجِعْ إِلَى رَبِّكَ فَاسْأَلْهُ التَّخْفِيفَ لِأُمَّتِكَ ، فَرَجَعْتُ ، فَوَضَعَ عَنِّي عَشْرًا ، فَرَجَعْتُ إِلَى مُوسَى فَقَالَ مِثْلَهُ ... فَارْجِعْ إِلَى رَبِّكَ فَاسْأَلْهُ التَّخْفِيفَ لِأُمَّتِكَ قَالَ : سَأَلْتُ رَبِّي حَتَّى اسْتَحْيَيْتُ وَلَكِنِّي أَرْضَى وَأُسَلِّمُ .
رواه البخاري ( 3674 ) ومسلم ( 162 ) .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. And you can find the reference in the Quran, surah 2, verse 253:

> تِلْكَ الرُّسُلُ فَضَّلْنَا بَعْضَهُمْ عَلَىٰ بَعْضٍ ۘ مِّنْهُم مَّن
>   كَلَّمَ اللَّـهُ ۖ وَرَفَعَ بَعْضَهُمْ دَرَجَاتٍ
>
> Those messengers - some of them We caused to exceed others. Among them
>   were those to whom Allah spoke, and He raised some of them in degree.

Note the plural form of messenger, which indicates more than one messenger had the privilege of having God speaking to him.

Refer to other answers for further information.

Comment: مَّن in مِّنْهُم مَّن كَلَّمَ اللَّـهُ can be singular as well as plural. Therefore, the translation could be: "amongst them _there is one_ whom God talked to" or "amongst them _there are those_ whom God talked to".

Answer (score 0):

Allah spoke to Adam while creating him and taught him before presented before the angels , Moses he spoke to but through a source and not at Mount Sinai   and Mohammad during Mehraj ,peace and blessing  be upon 
them.

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you cite some sources?